# what is that `etc` in operator precedence man page?

Tags: c, operators

`man operator` on macOS 10.12 shows `etc.`, what is it, a manpage bug?

```
OPERATOR(7)          BSD Miscellaneous Information Manual          OPERATOR(7)

NAME
     operator -- C operator precedence and order of evaluation

DESCRIPTION
           Operator                        Associativity
           --------                        -------------
           () [] -> .                      left to right
           ! ~ ++ -- - (type) * & sizeof   right to left
           * / %                           left to right
           + -                             left to right
           << >>                           left to right
           < <= > >=                       left to right
           == !=                           left to right
           &                               left to right
           ^                               left to right
           |                               left to right
           &&                              left to right
           ||                              left to right
           ?:                              right to left
           = += -= etc.                    right to left
           ,                               left to right

FILES
     /usr/share/misc/operator

BSD                              June 9, 1993                              BSD
```

Comment: et. cetera... it means all are not listed.. it includes others like /=

Comment: It's not an operator, it means "all the other assignment operators such as `*=`, `/=` etc.".

Comment: For "*etc*" please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one [you mentioned](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/operator/) does not list *all* the assignment operators, so it uses `etc.` [***(etc == et cetera)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera) to indicate that this is not an exhaustive list. This is **not a bug** , neither `etc.` is an operator / keyword in C (*thought of mentioning, FWIW*).

The [other version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/operator.7.html) lists all of them.

```
   = += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= ^= |=
```

The complete list is present in chapter §6.5.16, `C11`.

Comment: You don't speak Latin, do you? ;-)

Comment: @alk neither do I write. :)

Answer (score 2):

`etc.` stands for the Latin *et cetera*, which literally means "and the rest".  Here it indicates the whole family of "assignment operators": `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have an answer to your *immediate* question -- *etc.* just means they didn't list every single assignment operator here -- you could probably benefit from an additional piece of information:

Strictly speaking, there is no *operator precedence* in C. This means the C standard doesn't specify one. Instead, it specifies a *grammar* for expressions in a notation that's somewhat similar to [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (it uses single colons instead of `::=`, italics instead of pointy brackets, bold text instead of double quotes etc.). It looks for example like this:

**[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (latest C11 draft), §6.5.1:**

> *primary-expression* :
>         *identifier*
>         *constant*
>         *string-literal*
>         **(** *expression* **)**
>         *generic-selection*

This is equivalent to the following BNF:

```
<primary-expression> ::= <identifier> | <constant> | <string-literal>
                       | "(" <expression> ")" | <generic-selection>
```

From the full grammar spread across **§6.5**, it's possible to deduce an "*operator precedence*", but there's a catch with the *conditional operator* (`?:`): It doesn't allow an *assignment expression* on the right side of the colon, so although it's typically listed with a higher precedence than assignment, you would have to put the assignment in parantheses to make it a *primary expression* (see grammar snippet above). There's a [nice explanation on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) about this.